# Is it possible to install the Vim-LaTeX suite in cmder?

Tags: vim, latex, cmder

I use LaTeX (pdfLaTeX) and Vim quite often. I started with teXworks as a text editor for LaTeX, but since I found about the Vim-LaTeX suite I am trying to switch to Vim for everything.

However, I use **cmder** to run a bash shell in a windows computer, which comes with its own version of Vim installed, and I cannot manage to install the Vim-LaTeX suite on cmder.

First I download the folder, then extract it with 7-zip. I change the `.vimrc` as indicated in the website, and I check it is read when Vim starts. From here I have tried:

1. Pasting the files into the Vim74 folder in `cmder/.../Vim/Vim74/` replacing the existing duplicates, restarting the terminal (Total disaster, Vim crashes).
2. Pasting the files into the Vim74 folder in `cmder/.../Vim/Vim74/` *without* replacing the existing duplicates, restarting the terminal  (Total disaster, Vim crashes, again).
3. Creating a `~/vimfiles/`folder and putting the plugin on it (No effect).

I understand that installing a suite in cmder is different from doing it in windows or *nix systems, but I can't quite spot how to do it right.

Has anybody successfully installed the Vim-LaTeX suite in cmder? Is there any particular way of doing it?

Many thanks for your help!